# Opposite of TOP in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to retrieve the last few entries from a table. I can retrieve them using:

```
SELECT TOP n * 
FROM table 
ORDER BY id DESC
```

That I looked everywhere and that's the only answer I could find, But that way I get them in reverse order. I need them in the same order as they are in the table because it's for a messaging interface.

Comment: LIMIT n is same as TOP n. Goes last in the query. I think you need to change the order around. SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 10

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a derived table:

```
select id, ...
from
(
 select top n id, ...
 from t
 order by id desc
) dt
order by id
```

Comment: You need to specify an alias to the derived table. still got my vote up, though.

Comment: Sorry, didn't know about that SQL Server requirement. (Just checked for ANSI SQL compliance.) Will soon edit.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use a `ROW_NUMBER()` like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id DESC) AS RowNo
    FROM 
        yourTable
     ) AS t
WHERE
    (RowNO < @n)
ORDER BY
    id
```

Comment: Actually, this has the exact same result as well as performance (regardless of the indexes being used on the table).  I've thought about it myself and suggested it as well but then tested for performance and found it doesn't improve anything, so I've deleted my answer, since Jarlh's answer will work on any version for sql server, including 2000 (that doesn't support cte or window functions)